# Web API Null Content C# from Postman

Tags: c#, api, postman

Trying this so hard.
Been calling a function API from Postman but when I tried to check the content it is null and the method is GET but I have set to POST.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the receiving code

```
  [System.Web.Http.HttpPost()]
        // POST: Stream_Technical
        public void Update_Activation(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            

      
        
            string message = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            

        }
```

Comment: Change the function definition to `public void Update_Activation([Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FromBody] string content)` this will tell your endpoint to look at the body of the request for content

Comment: @AdamT..not using ASPNETCORE.. using .net framework...

Comment: If you change the content type in Postman from `json` to `text` in the Body section does that help?

Comment: @AdamT.. still null content

Comment: `[FromBody]` attribute is on both .NET Core and .NET Standard. Just the namespace is different. In regards to content, ASP expects to receive JSON formatted data (because You've specified `Content-type` to json) -> you should send a json object `{"key":"value"}`

Answer (score 0):

Change your method like this

```
   [HttpPost("collection")]
    // POST: Stream_Technical
    public void Update_Activation([FromBody]HttpRequestMessage request)
    {



        string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
      //  string message = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;


    }
```

Here I also attached a screen shot
[image]

post man request
[image]

Comment: Still null.. can you post the data you sent from the postman to the API?

Comment: updated the answer with postman request. please watch

Comment: On my solution in postman weather forecast is my controller name. Did this solution worked for you?